# Call variable from string value with React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Still learning React, having trouble finding the solution on this one.

I have a series of arrays in the initialState of a redux slice, i.e

```
const initialState = {
   sprites: {
      one: [1, 2, 3],
      two: [4, 5, 6],
      three: [7, 8, 9]
   }
}
```

In the app, when the user clicks on a particular button, among other things, I need to get the length of the relevant array.

Here's an example of the app:

```
<Component onClick={() => {dispatch(checkArray("one"))}/>
```

And the reducer:

```
checkArray: (state, {payload}) => {
   var arrayLength = state.sprites.{payload}.length;
   console.log(arrayLength);
}
```

Obviously this does not yield the desired effect. Using `{payload}` just throws an error. But how do I convert the payload in a way that will yield the numerical value of the length of the state.sprites.one.length array?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bracket notation.

```js
state.sprites[payload].length;
```

Comment: Sweet and simple, this was what I needed, thank you

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I'd like to expand on my question: say I have a variable in initialState such as ```oneIndex``` that I want to select with the the payload. i.e ```console.log(state.[payload]Index);```. Obviously this doesn't work, is there a way to concatenate the payload to a variable in that way?

Comment: @JustinRiley There is no easy way to do that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript

Comment: Once again thank you, bracket notation should work perfectly

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access a property of an object using a variable, use the square bracket notation. Use square brackets with the payload variable instead of dot notation and curly braces, like this:

```
checkArray: (state, {payload}) => {
var arrayLength = state.sprites[payload].length;
console.log(arrayLength);
}
```